# Can't set defaultValue of ToggleButtonGroup

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

When I load my `ToggleButtonRadio` component with data from `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` the `defaultValue` appears to populate with undefined and then doesn't update when data comes through. The component works as expect if data comes from `constructor(props)` as the `defaultValue` is set when the component is created.  I'm not getting an error so I can't figure out what I'm missing.

This is the [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-groups-checkbox-radio) component.

Component: `ToggleButtonRadio`

```
const ToggleButtonRadio = (props) => (
  <div>
    <ButtonToolbar key={props.name}>
      <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name={props.name} defaultValue={props.selectedOption}>
        {props.options.map(opt =>
          <ToggleButton
            key={opt}
            value={opt}
            onChange={props.controlFunc}>{opt}
          </ToggleButton>
        )}
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
    </ButtonToolbar>
  </div>
);
```

Page: `JobDetailsPage`

```
export default class JobDetailsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const jobsCollection = props.jobsCollection;
    const contractType = jobsCollection && jobsCollection.contractType;

    this.state = {
      contractType: contractType
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const jobsCollection = nextProps.jobsCollection;
    const contractType = jobsCollection && jobsCollection.contractType;

    this.setState({
      contractType: contractType
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ToggleButtonRadio
          options={['Permanent', 'Part time', 'Contract', 'Temp']}
          name={'contractType'}
          label={'Contract type'}
          controlFunc={this.handleInputChange}
          selectedOption={this.state.contractType}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that seems to work is to add a key.

```
<ToggleButtonRadio
 key={this.state.contractType ? 'loaded' : 'notLoaded'}
 options={['Permanent', 'Part time', 'Contract', 'Temp']}
 name={'contractType'}
 label={'Contract type'}
 controlFunc={this.handleInputChange}
 selectedOption={this.state.contractType}
/>
```